# How can I center this 4 buttons in this HTML page?

Tags: html, button, alignment, center

```html
<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
    <a href="#" class="button" style="width:40%">Hello 1</a>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a href="#" class="button" style="width:40%">Hello 2</a>
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
    <a href="#" class="button" style="width:40%">Hello 3</a>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a href="#" class="button" style="width:40%">Hello 4</a>
</div>
```

I would like have "Hello 1" and "Hello 2" nearby, on the left of "Hello 3" and "Hello 4". If it's possible, without CSS, but only HTML (style tag is good if it's need).

Comment: The stuff in `style="..."` is CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use     text-align: center on the parent div -

```
<div style="float: left; width: 50%;text-align:center">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is fix:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 50%;" align="center">
    <a href="#" class="button" style="width:40%">Hello 1</a>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a href="#" class="button" style="width:40%">Hello 2</a>
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 50%;"  align="center">
    <a href="#" class="button" style="width:40%">Hello 3</a>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <a href="#" class="button" style="width:40%">Hello 4</a>
```

You can check it here in https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/

Answer (score 0):

A basic solution using minimal CSS (only one style) and more clear to understand.

```html
<table style="margin: 0px auto;">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="button">Hello 1</a></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="button">Hello 3</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" class="button">Hello 2</a></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="button">Hello 4</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this solution, the CSS part is only used to center element on page.